# How to save output in music21 as a MIDI file?

Tags: python, audio, midi, music21

How do I save audio output in Python using the music21 module? I have read the entire [user's guide](http://music21.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usersGuide/index.html] of said module, but I couldn't find any information about saving output as an audio file that can be recognised by windows without any additional software (MIDI for example).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If `s` is your `Stream`, just call:

`fp = s.write('midi', fp='pathToWhereYouWantToWriteIt')`

or to hear it immediately

`s.show('midi')`

Answer (score 5):

Somewhere in this User's Guide Chapter 8, there is some important information about opening and saving file in many formats:
http://web.mit.edu/music21/doc/usersGuide/usersGuide_08_installingMusicXML.html

if you have made your own music called 'stream1', you can easily save it as MIDI file like this:

```
stream1.write("midi", "blah.mid")
```

I am still new to this, but I think that's simpler than having to open file, etc.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [`MidiFile`](http://music21.readthedocs.org/en/latest/moduleReference/moduleMidi.html?highlight=midifile#midifile) object, which knows how to [write a midi file](http://music21.readthedocs.org/en/latest/moduleReference/moduleMidi.html?highlight=midifile#music21.midi.MidiFile.write).

But the documentation on how to use it is non-existant.

However, in its [source](https://github.com/cuthbertLab/music21/blob/c6fc39204c16c47d1c540b545d0c9869a9cafa8f/music21/midi/__init__.py) there is a [testBasicExport](https://github.com/cuthbertLab/music21/blob/c6fc39204c16c47d1c540b545d0c9869a9cafa8f/music21/midi/__init__.py#L1471) test, probably it's a good start, it does something like this:

```
mt = MidiTrack(1)

# duration, pitch, velocity
data = [[1024, 60, 90], [1024, 50, 70], [1024, 51, 120],[1024, 62, 80], ]

# Omit this part here, but full code in the links above
populateTrackFromData(mt, data)

mf = MidiFile()
mf.ticksPerQuarterNote = 1024 # cannot use: 10080
mf.tracks.append(mt)

mf.open('/src/music21/music21/midi/out.mid', 'wb')
mf.write()
mf.close()
```

Comment: use stream.write('midi') instead as below.  The MidiFile is mainly an internal use function.